# how to remove sitemap.aspx in dnn6

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

i need to remove sitemap.aspx from the site.
In dnn 6,there is a sitemap.aspx page that simply shows an xml sitemap.i cannot edit/remove that file.so i need to remove  that page and recreate it with a simple html sitemap.

NOTE:the page name should be sitemap.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitemap.aspx isn't a physical page you can delete.

You can, however, rename it to something else.  It's in your web.config file, under the 'handlers' section.  Just look for sitemap.aspx, and change it to something else, like 'searchenginesitemap.aspx'.  Don't forget to update your robots.txt file to point to the new sitemap name, or go to the various webmaster console pages in search engines and advise them of the new location.

Answer (score 1):

The sitemap.aspx is used to create the xml sitemap for search engines.  By changing this you break this functionality and limit the search-ability of your site.

That being said, in Host Settings->Advance Settings you could setup a new Friendly Url that would match .*/sitemap.aspx to another url/page on your site.

Answer (score 1):

I have long stopped using DNN's native sitemap.aspx... ITS BUGGY!... and here is how i found out.

I generated my own "CLEAN" sitemap.xml using a free 3rd party tool. And uploaded it to the root of my DNN website.... re-submitted the the domainname.com/sitemap.xml to Google via web master tools and as a result we now get a 1ST PAGE and TOP 10 RANKING.

Mostly in the top 5... where as before using DNN's native sitemap.aspx we would get random errors which was pretty ANNOYING. Plus we got very bad Google Page Rank, But those were just my findings of better results. Note:I also place the location of the sitemap within the robots.txt file...

Although i will admit that it is extremely ANNOYING that you cannot just edit the DNN Sitemap url. This creates an issue if you've built the the site on a test server and then migrate over to production... your DNN Sitemap url only reads the firs portal alias from when you first developed the site.

Anyway, this was my findings... others may vary... just sharing.